# compile only a certain specified part of the whole document?

Tags: comments

I know there is a package called `comment`, which can let `latex` ignore some text.

How can I do the inverse? 
I want to compile just a small segment of the whole `tex` file and let `latex` ignore other part.

**EDIT**

This is desirable when I'm looking for a specific coordinate in [drawing on an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz).

But I do not want an solution just for handling figures.

I've been using ktikz for drawing tikz figures, and the following to generate the pdf image and the complete latex source.

```

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="${1%.*}"".TeXTiKz"

echo "    \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview} 
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} 
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm} 

\begin{document} 
    \input{$1} 
\end{document}"     > $filename

echo $filename

pdflatex $filename
```

Comment: You can use [`ktikz`](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) to draw Tikz images.

Comment: If your document is very long, you can split it into several TeX files, use `\include` on the main document to join them all and `\includeonly{name}` on the preamble to compile just the content of name.tex.

Comment: @giordano, Thank you. I do use ktikz. But when it's not about drawing or figures, is `includeonly` the only way to do this (as per @LuanResende 's comment)?

Comment: @Hongying well, that's a possibility.  But if you want to compile only a small region `includeonly` isn't really useful.  You can try some editors allowing preview of regions of the document, such as [Emacs+AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html) or TeXstudio

Comment: @giordano, Oh, I never know that under Emacs we can preview regions of the document. By the way, I use Latex-Box with vim, but maybe I should view Emacs+AUCTeX as a powerful latex editor rather a general text editor or an operating system (just joking. Thank you. :) ).

Comment: The answer and following comment to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116869/proper-tool-for-charts-in-tex tells you how to put some of your `TeX` in a separate file that you can both compile by itself and `\input` in your full document. The `standalone` package makes the magic work.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution are `Makefiles`:

```
main = main-doc
plots-dir = plots

# all tikz-pictures in separated *.tex in folder plots
plots-tex :=  $(wildcard $(plots-dir)/*.tex)
vpath %.tex $(plots-dir)

# rule to make all plots
make_tikz_plots : $(plots-tex:.tex=-preview.pdf)

# 'packages.tex' can be the same as used in 'main-doc.tex' but should
# at least contains the needed TikZ package and desired libraries
# '\externaldocument' is from the package 'xr' which will use
# 'main-doc.aux' to create the right '\ref' etc
plots/%-preview.pdf : %.tex
    @echo Generating $<
    pdflatex --shell-escape --jobname="$(<:.tex=-preview)" \
    "\documentclass[compress,10pt]{beamer}"\
    "\input{packages}"\
    "\externaldocument{$(main)}"\
    "\begin{document}\tikzset{external/force remake}"\
    "\input{$(<:.tex=)}\end{document}"
```

All TikZ-pictures are saved in individual *.tex-files in a directory `plots`.  Running `make` will generate for every of these file a `*-preview.pdf` using the packages defined in `packages.tex`.  With the package `xr` even references will be correctly resolved from the main document `main-doc.tex`.

(This is more a comment, but as a new user I can't yet add comment :/)

Comment: Thank you, a long detailed "comment" becomes an answer! :). By the way,what's the benefits (from your experience of using it)? I've noticed there are people use makefile for compiling latex file, but I've never tried that.

Comment: I'm not sure, if there is any real benefit :).  My main use is/was with gnuplot's `epslatex` or `tikz` terminal to test the fonts and references from the main document in descriptions individually.  Maybe somebody has a more advanced Makefile using the `external` tikz-library (so the preview-pdfs would be the actual includeded pictures).