# Creating plots in Latex - easy to learn?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I am currently working on my summer project for which I created the following plot with Mathematica:

[image]

Now I am not 100% satisfied with the results and one of my professors recommended
PGF and TikZ. The problem is I don't know anything about PGF and TikZ and I have to submit my project in 1.5 months.

So should I try to learn how to create `beautiful` plots with PGF and TikZ (i.e. is it possible to learn it in a week or so?) or should I just stick with my Mathematica plot? And are there even other alternatives?

edit:
As a few people have requested it, here is the Mathematica code:

```
max = 102000;
psi[x0_, y0_] := Module[{x = x0, y = y0, n = 2, c = 0}, 
  Do[If[Max[First[Transpose[FactorInteger[n]]]] <= y, c++]; n++;, {x}]; c]
data = Parallelize[Table[{n, psi[n, Ceiling[Sqrt[n]]]/n*100}, {n, 2, max, 1000}]];
p1 = Plot[{PrimePi[Sqrt[n]]/PrimePi[n]*100}, {n, 2, max}, PlotRange -> {{0, max}, {0, 55}},
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thick}, Epilog -> {Inset[Style["\[Pi](\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(n\)]\))/\[Pi](n)",
   FontSize -> 13, Bold], {40000, 7}], Inset[Style["\[Psi](n,\!\(\*SqrtBox[\(n\)]\))/n",
   FontSize -> 13, Bold], {max/2, 43}]}];
p2 = ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, max}, {0, 100}}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Gray}];
p3 = Plot[{30}, {n, 2, max}, PlotRange -> {{0, max}, {0, 100}}, PlotStyle -> {Gray, Dashed}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, AxesLabel -> Table[Text[Style[{"n", "%"}[[i]], FontSize -> 13, Bold, Italic]],
   {i, 1, 2}], Ticks -> {Table[1/10*(max - 2000)*k, {k, 0, 9, 3}], Table[10 k, {k, 1, 10}]}]
```

Comment: I asked a similar question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116869/proper-tool-for-charts-in-tex. If you are reasonably comfortable with `LaTeX` you can learn enough `pgfplots` functionality in a week or so to do a 1.5 month project - particularly with help from this site - but I don't know whether TeX is powerful/convenient enough for the actual calculations you need. Those may call for mathematica, in which case the time invested in TeX may not pay off.

Comment: The picture you've posted  certainly is easy enough in `pgfplots`, with the proviso mentioned by @EthanBolker than you may have a little 'fun' with the calculations. `gnuplot` can help out with that, again depending on calculation complexity.

Comment: The question also is, does pgfplots allow me to use things like the prime-counting function pi and the counting function for smooth numbers phi?

Comment: In my opinion the easiest thing to do is 1) elaborate the data you want to plot with some powerful program like `Mathematica`. 2) produce a file with the data and use `pgfplots` to plot it

Comment: The mathematical functions available in `pgfplots` can not compete with Mathematica. That is not the point though, I export all complicated data to ascii files and use pgfplots to create the plots. Just try it out for an afternoon or so, it is not that complicated and the manual is great.

Comment: The plots produced my `Mathematica` ar rather disappointing, especially for the recent version (>5). `TikZ`, with or without `pgfplots` is surely the best solution to provide nice looking graphs, but you can't make advanced calculations -- as you apparently need -- with it. 

An intermediate solution, if you don't want to invest the time and effort to learn, is to use `gnuplot` to plotdata exported from `Mathematica`.

Comment: If you already have the data, one week is even too much. Edit your question and include some data (of 10-15 rows) otherwise this question is boring :P No seriously, just start with the manual it's quite straightforward but don't rush because it needs some initial care. As long as we can save another soul from matlab or mathematica (yes no capital letters, they can sue me) it would be great.

Comment: Depending on the other plots you need to make, Asymptote might better suit your needs. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39577/what-are-the-relative-strengths-of-tikz-and-asymptote for a comparison between TikZ and Asymptote and some discussion on plot making.

Comment: And what about the `Mathematica` code? Why not to put it too? If it isn't too long, of course.

Comment: @m0nhawk I edited my question.

Comment: @Jhor: Your link points to an empty document at writeLaTeX...

Comment: Edited comment :  
You can have a Look at [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/line-plot-example/) to have an idea about the plotting of tabulated data.

Comment: @Jhor In my opinion that's not a good *initial* point for a beginner.

Comment: I hardly used Mathematica until now, I usually use Matlab. For Matlab, there is a nice script, called matlab2tikz https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz which converts the data of a matlab plot into tikz. This actually works really good. Maybe there is something like that for Mathematica as well.