# Approach to creating graphics in book - TikZ, SVG, PDF, Inkscape?

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, pdf, svg, excel

I have a series of "charts" I created with Excel (before discovering `LaTeX`) to show the ROM character patterns for an old computer for inclusion in a book on retrocomputing.

[image]

My dilemma is how to approach inserting these into the book.  I'm assuming each should be a separate image so I can allow `LaTeX` to format them properly in a grid pattern, but I'm also wondering if `TikZ` or even Inkscape would be a better approach.

I need 128 characters total.  The character in the lower-left is from a TTF font.  I'm using `XeTeX` so the inclusion of that font is no problem.

What would be the "best" approach in terms of learning curve, convenience, and appearance in the final document?

Comment: Can you obtain the huge characters by TTF scaling, or must be a different approach to obtain the same look that this example? All these details are needed? An approach could be http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/fitting-text-into-a-box-over-a-pic. Another, make a `tabular` environment model and fill cells as needed.

Comment: I believe I could scale the TTF, but I'd prefer to reproduce the charts exactly as they are because of the information they convey (bit patterns, data, ASCII code, screen code, and appearance). The grid represents the pixels on screen (each character is 8 x 8).

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116869/proper-tool-for-charts-in-tex. Also: Excel can  save selections as pdf, which you can crop with `pdfcrop` and insert as graphics.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please note the `symbol node` style which should have the right font setup for the special font. My [`positioning-plus`](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex) has been used for the keys `west below` which can be replaced with original `positioning` and TikZ keys: `west below=<distance> of node` is the same as `below=<distance> of node.south west, anchor=north west`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}% 
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning-plus}
\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.append tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.append code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.prefix tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.prefix code=\tikzset{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\letterset}{\pgfqkeys{/letter}}
\letterset{
  @int/start chain/.style={start chain=ch#1 going right},
  columns/.initial=8,
  rows/.initial={0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  column width/.initial=+.5cm,
  row height/.initial=+.6cm,
  %
  every letter picture/.tikz={
    node distance=+0pt,
    every node/.append style={
      minimum width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/column width},
      minimum height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/row height},
      text depth=+0pt,
      outer sep=+0pt,
    }},
  every header label/.tikz={font=\tiny,rotate=90,inner sep=+0pt,outer sep=+0pt},
  every cell node/.tikz={draw=gray, ultra thin},
  every 1 node/.tikz={fill=black},
  every 0 node/.tikz={},
  data column node/.tikz={
    align=right,
    text width=\widthof{000}
  },
  symbol node/.tikz={
    font=\ttfamily}% Here should stand the command for the XeTeX font
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\letterChart}[4][]{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/letter}{#1}%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/letter/columns}\letter@Columns
    \pgfmathsetbasenumberlength{\letter@Columns}%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/letter/rows}\letter@Rows
    \tikzpicture[/letter/every letter picture/.try, /letter/@int/start chain/.list/.expanded={0,1,...,\letter@Columns}]
      \node[anchor=west,/letter/head node/.try] (letter@head) {Bit Values of Pixels};
        \foreach \letter@Power in {1,...,\letter@Columns} {
          \ifnum\letter@Power=1\tikzset{/letter/@int/first node/.tikz={west below=of letter@head}}\fi
          \node[on chain=ch0,/letter/@int/first node/.try,/letter/header node/.try,label={[/letter/every header label/.try]center:\pgfmathprint{int(2^(\letter@Columns-\letter@Power))}}] {};
        }
        \foreach \letter@Row[count=\c@prevRow from 0, count=\c@Row] in \letter@Rows {%
          \pgfmathbin{\letter@Row}
          \edef\letter@Digits{\expandafter\letter@IncludeComma\pgfmathresult\stop@Letter}
          \foreach \letter@Digit[count=\c@Col] in \letter@Digits{
            \ifnum\c@Col=1\tikzset{/letter/@int/first node/.tikz={below=of ch\c@prevRow-begin}}\fi
            \node[on chain=ch\c@Row,/letter/@int/first node/.try,/letter/every cell node/.try, /letter/every \letter@Digit\space node/.try] {};
          }
          \node[/letter/data column node/.try, right=\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/column width} of ch\c@Row-end] (letter@datacolumn) {\letter@Row};
        }
        \node[anchor=base east, /letter/head node/.try] at (letter@datacolumn.east|-letter@head.base) {Data};

        \node[below=\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/row height} of letter@datacolumn, /letter/data column node/.try] (letter@ascii) {#3};
        \node[mid left=of letter@ascii] {ASCII Code:};
        \node[below=of letter@ascii, /letter/data column node/.try] (letter@screen) {#4};
        \node[mid left=of letter@screen] {Screen Code:};

        \node[anchor=base west, /letter/symbol node/.try] at (letter@ascii.base-|letter@head.base west) {#2};
    \endtikzpicture
  \endgroup
}
\def\letter@IncludeComma#1#2{%
  #1%
  \ifx\stop@Letter#2
    \expandafter\pgfutil@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstofone
  \fi
  {,\letter@IncludeComma#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\letterChart[rows={60,102,110,110,96,98,60,0}]{@}{64}{0}
\letterChart[rows={24,60,102,102,126,102,102,0}]{A}{65}{1}
\letterChart[rows={124,102,102,124,102,102,124,0}]{B}{66}{2}

\letterset{
  every letter picture/.append tikz={node distance=+3pt},
  /tikz/nodes={minimum width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/column width}-3pt,
        minimum height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/letter/row height}-3pt},
  every cell node/.append tikz={shape=circle,draw=none},
  column width/.initial=+.5cm,
  row height/.initial=+.5cm}

\letterChart[rows={60,102,110,110,96,98,60,0}]{@}{64}{0}
\letterChart[rows={24,60,102,102,126,102,102,0}]{A}{65}{1}
\letterChart[rows={124,102,102,124,102,102,124,0}]{B}{66}{2}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Really nice. Exactly what i was looking for. I'm not familiar enough with TikZ to know exactly what this is doing, but it appears that it's actually calculating which cells are filled from the data?

Comment: I got this to work, but I noticed that each character grid takes up an entire page.  I didn't notice any errors when compiling, but was wondering if this is the expected behaviour or something that I've done wrong.  Is it possible to arrange each character grid onto a page in a (for example) 8 x 10 grid whilst maintaining the headings I've used for my template?

Comment: @KevinP.Kilburn That is the work of the `standalone` class, you usually don’t use that class for your real document (or only to include PDFs created by it). With a class like `article` you get your usual TikZ picture which can be placed as everything else. If you replace the `\tikzpicture` with `\scope` (and the same for `\endtikzpicture`) you can use `\letterChart` inside a TikZ picture (for example a `\matrix`).

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Ethan Bolker, I would export them directly from Excel as a `pdf`. Place all the `pdf` files in a single folder. Then you can use the following loop to crop all the `pdfs`:

```
for img in *.pdf
    do
    convert -quality 100 -crop 300x100+20+50 "$img" "new_$img"
    echo $img
done
```

where: `300` is the width, `100` is the height, `20` is the cropped portion on x axis, `50` is the cropped portion on y axis.

`--> (20,50)` is the top left corner of your image.

If you have problems with the scale, you can add `-scale 100%` to the command.

**Note:** for this loop to be useful, all the characters you are going to export must be the same size.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `pdfcrop` (http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I guess `pdfcrop` should work as well. I do not know the exact syntax though...

Comment: Why would the PDF files need to be cropped? Are the values here only for illustrative purposes?

Comment: @KevinP.Kilburn: The values given for the cropping are indeed for illustrative purposes, as well as the values given for the repositioning of the new image.

The files are cropped in the case where the entire page is exported from Excel as a `pdf`.

Comment: I see now.  When I export a single image from Excel, it actually puts it on a whole page.

Comment: @KevinP.Kilburn Exactly, so when you are done exporting all the images, you can crop them with the above routine with the right values (width, height and position of the top left corner)

Comment: `pdfcrop` comes with miktex, probably with other distributions too. `pdfcrop foo.pdf bar.pdf` removes the whitespace surrounding real stuff in `foo` and puts output in `bar`. If you need to  rescale in your document, use `\resizebox`.

Answer (score 5):

An attempt only with LaTeX from the scratch:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl,xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating,hhline}
\providecommand{\X}{\cellcolor{red!50}}
\providecommand{\CR}{\hhline{--------~-}}
%\renewcommand\arraystretch{1} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{9}{l}{Bit values of Pixels} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Data}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 128\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 64\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 32\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 16\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 8\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 4\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 2\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{sideways}\small 1\end{sideways}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
\CR &    &    & \X & \X &    &    &  &  & 24\\
\CR &    & \X & \X & \X & \X &    &  &  & 60\\
\CR & \X & \X &    &    & \X & \X &  &  & 102\\
\CR & \X & \X &    &    & \X & \X &  &  & 102\\
\CR & \X & \X & \X & \X & \X & \X &  &  & 126\\
\CR & \X & \X &    &    & \X & \X &  &  & 102\\
\CR & \X & \X &    &    & \X & \X &  &  & 102\\
\CR &    &    &    &    &    &    &  &  & 0\\
\CR
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\centering}p{1cm}}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{10-10} 
A & \multicolumn{8}{r|}{ASCII Code:} & 64\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{10-10} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{r|}{Screen Code:} & \\
\cline{10-10} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```